# Conv2D model in tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I try to feed a Conv2D network with a X_train of size (2000, 20, 10, 12) and a y_train of size (2000, 12) - one output per channel as it is a multi-to multi classification.
I build my model (code below) and compile it without problem.
But when I want to feed it with X_train and y_train, while I give the right size of the input, the model gives an error message :

```
    ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:
', array([[ 1., -1., -1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1., ..., -1., -1.,  1.],
           ...,
           [ 1., -1., -1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1., -1., -1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1., ..., -1., -1.,  1.]]))
```

Here is the code (simplified) :

```
###  Part 0. Import 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Flatten, Add, TimeDistributed, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from util_model import *  # own code for data management
from util_LSTM import *   # own code for organizing the X matrix into 3D matrix for LSTM model

### Part 1. Assumptions about the data
horiz = 1                          ### time horizon of the investment in days ###
seq_length = 20                     ### number of days for enriching the LSTM
step = 1                            ### time lag within LSTM memory batch
eval_trigger = 0.001
nn_start = 250                    ### initial value of X and Y matrices out of the total dataset
nn_size = 2500                     ### length of the X & Y matrices starting from lstmStart index
proportionTrain = 0.8

### Part 2. Organizing the data into X_train, X_test, y_train & y_test for Conv2D
dataX, dataY = get_model_data(dbInput, dbList, ric, horiz)
Xs, ys = LSTM_create_dataset(dataX, dataY, seq_length, step)      # slide over seq_length for a 3D matrix
Xslen = len(Xs)
if i == 0:
    yconv.append(ys)
    Xconv.append(Xs)
    minlen = Xslen
    i += 1
else:
    i += 1
    if minlen == Xslen:
        yconv.append(ys)
        Xconv.append(Xs)
    else:
        print('data ',i,' not added for size mismatch')
Xconv = np.array(Xconv)
yconv = np.array(yconv)   
Xconv = np.reshape(Xconv, (Xconv.shape[1], Xconv.shape[2], Xconv.shape[3], Xconv.shape[0]))
yconv = np.reshape(yconv, (yconv.shape[1], yconv.shape[2], yconv.shape[0]))
## Xconv is a 4D matrix and yconv is a 2D matrix
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), (res_train, res_test) = CONV_train_test_return(Xconv, yconv, nn_start, nn_size, proportionTrain)
(X_train, X_test), (train_mean, train_std) = get_CONV_minmaxscaleX(X_train, X_test)

### Part 3. Model assumptions
validation_split = 0.1
model = keras.Sequential()
dropout = 0.2
optimizer = 'adam'                      ### Optimizer of the compiled model
learning = 0.001
loss = 'mean_squared_error'
verbose = 1                         ## 0 = hidden computation  //  1 = computation printed
batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
layer_1 = 128
layer_2 = 64
activ1 = 'relu'
activ2 = 'tanh'
activ3 = 'hard_sigmoid'

# available layers
layer_maxpool2D = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding = 'valid', strides= None, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]))
layer_dense1 = Dense(units= layer_1, activation = 'relu')
layer_dense2 = Dense(units= layer_2, activation = activ1)
layer_LSTM1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_1, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = False, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_LSTMstack1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
layer_LSTMstack2 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu' , return_sequences = True)
layer_LSTMstackend = keras.layers.LSTM(units=layer_2, activation = 'relu')
layer_conv2D1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 12, kernel_size= (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]))
layer_output = Dense(units = 1)

# Model architecture 
#model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = 12, kernel_size= (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]))))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 12, kernel_size= (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3])))
model.add(layer_maxpool2D)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(layer_dense2)
model.add(layer_output)

### Part 4. Model compile & Train
model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer = optimizer)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, validation_split = validation_split, verbose = verbose)
```

The model stops there with the error message shared above.
Any idea why and how to address it ?
Thx in advance

Comment: Why are you providing an `input_shape` to the second layer (i.e., the max pooling layer)?

Comment: I withdraw the input_shape but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: Why are you using mean_squared_error on a classification task? You should be using categorical_crossentropy as a loss function. Also, shouldn't your output layer have 12 units for the 12 possible classes?

Comment: In fact, for each of the 12 channels, I have 2 categories, so that my y_train should be (2000, 12, 2) if I have a classification between two categories... or (200,2, 12)???